# hide bootstrap navbar when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to hide/show a Bootstrap navbar when scrolling down/up but it does not seem to work. I'm stuck and I would really appreciate some help here. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Please bear in mind I'm learning how to use Bootstrap and got very little knowledge about jQuery. 
When I check the code with the browser console it does not show any error.
I have also tried `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` as well as addClass and removeClass functions with no luck.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var banner = $("#navscroll");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= banner.height()) {
      $("#banner").hide();

    } else {
      $("banner").show();
    }
  });

});

console.log();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: azure;
}

.divi {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#divi1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#divi2 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Stylesheet for Mysite -->


  <title>My Site</title>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Banner -->
  <div id="banner" class="container-fluid">
    <nav id="navscroll" class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light fixed-top">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Site</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Me<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">What I do</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Find Me</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- Banner -->

  <!-- Divs -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="divi1" class="divi"></div>
    <div id="divi2" class="divi"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Divs -->



  <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You forgot `#` in `$("banner").show();`

Comment: This will help http://jsfiddle.net/nwV2r/699/

Comment: Sanchit Patiyal thanks for this. I'm trying to implement it in my code but it does not work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues preventing your code from showing the navbar back when scrolling up:

1. The line `$("banner").show();` => there is "#" missing before `banner`.
2. When hiding an element, its height isn't kept. Therefore, when testing the nvarbar height after it's already hidden, you get an unexpected result. Therefore, I recommend to save the height in advance and compare it to the saved variable.

The fixed code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var banner_height = $("#navscroll").height();
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var currScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= banner_height && currScrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
      $("#banner").hide();
    } else {
      $("#banner").show();
    }
    lastScrollTop = currScrollTop;

  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: azure;
}

.divi {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#divi1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#divi2 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Stylesheet for Mysite -->

  <title>My Site</title>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Banner -->
  <div id="banner" class="container-fluid">
    <nav id="navscroll" class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light fixed-top">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Site</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Me<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">What I do</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Find Me</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- Banner -->

  <!-- Divs -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="divi1" class="divi"></div>
    <div id="divi2" class="divi"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Divs -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works like a charm! I don't know why I could not see this before.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Sorry @Tomer, one more thing. When I scroll up regardless of my scroll position, my navbar does not show. It only shows if I'm at the top of the page. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: @AtlantisNaranja, I edited the javascript code in the snippet to always show the navbar when scrolling up, regardless of the scroll position. The change I did: added another variable to remember the last scroll position to figure out the scroll direction. Once that is done, I'm adding it to the condition to make sure we perform the relevant action each time. Please upvote the answer if it satisfies your requirements :)

Comment: thanks again! this is exactly for I was aiming for! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to define banner height outside the scroll function and also you forgot #, your script looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                var banner = $("#navscroll");
                var bannerHeight = banner.height();
                $(window).scroll(function(){
                    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                    if (scroll >= bannerHeight){
                        $("#banner").hide();
                    } else {
                        $("#banner").show();
                    }
                });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the code for you and added some comments,
try to open console and scroll to see what is happening.

Basicly you were comparing scroll height to the banner height which changed from 40 to -16 when it got hidden, so you have to save it before.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var banner = $("#navscroll");
             var bannerStartHeight = $("#navscroll").height();
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                console.log("SCROLL: "+scroll)
                console.log("BANNER HEIGHT:"+banner.height())
                console.log("BANNER START HEIGHT: "+bannerStartHeight)
                if (scroll >= bannerStartHeight){
                    $("#banner").hide();
                } else {
                    $("#banner").show(); //here u forgot a #
                }
            });
    });
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

`Banner height` should be calculated outside the `scroll` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var banner = $("#navscroll");
  var bannerHgt = banner.height();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= bannerHgt) {
      $("#banner").hide();
    } else {
      $("#banner").show();
    }
  });

});

console.log();
```

```css
 body{
    
            background-color: azure;
        }

        .divi{

            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }

        #divi1{

            background-color: red;
        }

        #divi2{

            background-color: greenyellow;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Stylesheet for Mysite -->  
      
      
    <title>My Site</title> 
         
  </head>
            
  <body>
      
    <!-- Banner --> 
    <div id="banner" class="container-fluid">
        <nav id="navscroll" class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light fixed-top">
          <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Site</a>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Me<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">What I do</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Find Me</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>  
    </div> 
    <!-- Banner -->
    
    <!-- Divs -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="divi1" class="divi"></div>  
        <div id="divi2" class="divi"></div>  
    </div>  
    <!-- Divs -->  
      
 

    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```